# TypeScript: extending existing JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a pure JavaScript object (let's call it O) from a certain library, with its interface in an ambient namespace, e.g.:

```
declare namespace N {
    interface IO {
        // properties...
    }
}
```

I need to create a TypeScript class, which will extend this JavaScript object. The mechanism for extending it is provided by the library, so I cannot use the native TS inheritance, yet I need to have access to all the properties of this JS object, which I'm extending. I tried declaring a class which implements this interface and extending it:

```
declare class DummyO implements N.IO {
    // copy-paste everything from N.IO
}

class MyRealClass extends DummyO {
}
```

Now I have access to all the properties, but also two problems:

1. I had to copy-paste the whole interface, which is not so practical.
2. TypeScript doesn't create any definition for DummyO (which is good), but in the same time tries to extend it using its native mechanism (which is bad, since DummyO doesn't really exist).

So the question is - how to work around it? How to create a TS class, which effectively extends this native object? Or maybe there's another way to convince TS that I'm really inheriting O without all that hassle?

Comment: Why doesn't `MyRealClass` directly implement `N.IO`?

Comment: N.IO is already fully implemented by the JavaScript object (O). Will TS allow copy-pasting N.IO without actual implementation?

Comment: How can N.IO be an implementation if it is an interface? I might be missing something, but this seems tow work fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20N%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20IO%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09theProperty%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyRealClass%20implements%20N.IO%20%7B%0D%0A%09theProperty%3A%20'value'%0D%0A%7D. I'm not sure what the extra value of DummyO is.

Comment: The interface is already implemented by the real JS object, which I wish to extend in TS, but I don't have the TS class for it. That's the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only working solution I know of is pretty much copy-pasting the interface into the class:

```
declare namespace N {
    interface IO {
        // example properties:
        a: number;
        f(): number;
    }
}


class MyRealClass implements N.IO {
    // copy IO
    a: number;
    f: () => number;

    // add "real" members later...
}
```

It isn't pretty, but that's what you get with custom inheritance solutions in libraries.

Comment: This seems wrong for most use cases. The answer does not include any reference to the external JS object at all.

Comment: As the question states, external references and inheritance is handled by the external library.

Comment: But that means that there is some code that is not covered by typescript. Maybe that's why you have to duplicate the properties, because if the code was covered, the properties would be inherited correctly. Can you please provide some example code?

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I'm not commenting the question but the answer which is obviously wrong. Would you please share some example code?

Comment: An example would be melonJS and their inheritance model: http://melonjs.github.io/melonJS/docs/me.Object.html#extend
If you want  to use melon in TS (and have typings), you need to somehow be able to combine TS classes with me.Object, and this answer shows how to do it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MelonJS, but it seems that declaring ambient class would be the way to go. Could you please share some *actual* code example that demonstrates the problem you have?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot since I'm not using melon for months now. I don't remember if ambient classes worked or not. Maybe someone will stumble upon this particular problem again and try.